# Laravel store request not found (using axios)

Tags: php, laravel, axios

I just have a question about using axios POST & STORE request. How do I post my data to a certain table?

I tried changing Customer to Psdvsystem and it works just fine. I also changed the table name from customers to psdvsystems in my database and it still works fine.

Store request in my Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
     $cd = new Customer;
     $cd->Customer = $request->Customer;
     $cd->Address = $request->Address;
     $cd->save();
}
```

I just want to be able to post even though my table name is customers. Thanks, any help is appreciated.

Comment: For the model Customer the table name most be 'customers', otherwise add `protected $table = 'customers';` in the model. Take a look on [model conventions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions).